# Linkedin Api how to get groups details through people search

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I need to get the groups of an user,

```
IN.API.Raw("/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,industry,summary,num-connections,headline,group-memberships:(group:(id)))?first-name=ramesh&last-name=kotha&count="+25).result(function(result, metadata) {
//got the details here
}
```

when i use **result.values[0].person.groupMembership.group.id** it is saying undefined.
How to get the groups of a user.

Comment: What is the status of your request? I get 400 (Bad request)

Comment: No, am getting the result but with out groups info.

Comment: it looks like you're missing a bracket in the URL:
`"/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,industry,summary,num-connections,headline,group-memberships:(group:(id))))?first-name=ramesh&last-name=kotha&count="+25`

Comment: Nope, it is just a typo error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesting the requests to build the objects would work:

```
IN.API.Raw("/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,industry,summary‌,group-memberships,num-connections,headline))?first-name=ramesh&last‌​-name=kotha&count="+25)
.result(function(result, metadata) {
     console.log(result);

     for(person in result.people.values){
        console.log(person);
       IN.API.Raw()
          .url("/people/" + result.people.values[person].id + "/group-memberships:(group:(id,name),membership-state)")

         .result(function(result, metadata){

            console.log(result);
          });

    }


})
```